# make an image in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, hyperledger-indy, indy-node

actually i have a project to develop ssi concept, and i use sovrin platform to develop ssi concept with indy network. and in the indy network documentation I followed the steps that were ordered, the first step was to create an image with docker. and when I practice the steps, I get out the following error message:

```
[internal] load build definition from indy-pool.dockerfile
 sha256:549f00990a020075d136b14c21bb5758301e2db9ee6c7c664706a50642d2ff5d
 transferring dockerfile: 71B 0.0s done
 ERROR: error from sender: resolve : CreateFile ci: The system cannot find the file specified.
 > [internal] load build definition from indy-pool.dockerfile:
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: error from sender: resolve : CreateFile ci: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

and here is the code I use

```
docker network create --subnet 10.0.0.0/8 indy_pool_network
docker build --build-arg pool_ip=10.0.0.2 -f ci/indy-pool.dockerfile -t indy_pool .
docker run -d --ip="10.0.0.2" --net=indy_pool_network indy_pool
```

what I'm trying at the moment is trying to create an image on my docker by following the guide or steps using the indy  network  sdk

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] a good question and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to the question and [edit] it (preferably with your code, the provided input and the expected output) in order to get a (useful) answer. Show what you have tried and where you got stuck to maximize the chances to get help. Please do not post images that represent the code, the program input or the expected output. Put the code or data directly in the question surrounded by lines containing only `\`\`\`` (the formatting is preserved between these markers).

Comment: In its current status, this question will probably be closed soon because it is difficult to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

judging by your error code, because you haven't created a folder or it could be that the image you are using is not found